# webBrowser .Url is not being applied

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

This one is mystical. I'm updating my `webBrowser1` control from my code like this:

```
string hostname = textBox1.Text;
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=" + hostname);
webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

Every odd number tries work OK.
Every even number tries simply refreshes the `webBrowser` with the last compname.
So:

```
1. set textbox comp1 goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp1
2. set textbox comp2 goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp1
3. set textbox comp3 goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp3
4. set textbox comp956 goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp3
5. set textbox comp111 goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp111
6. set textbox comp goes to http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=comp111
etc...
```

How on earth is that even possible?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? For example an event where webBrowser is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
webBrowser1.Stop();
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=" + hostname);
```

Instead of the old code.

Comment: The [Stop method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) causes loading of the previous url to stop. It seems that WebBrowser doesn't accept new url's before (some parts?) of the previous page have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `Url` then `Refresh` is the correct procedure.

Try doing

```
var uri = new Uri(@"http://mydomain/comp.php?compname=" + hostname);
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
```